# Powershell Break : not switched to next statement/method

Tags: powershell, break

Can someone please help me, as i could not call second method after break executed in first method.

```
Function First ()
{


write-host "I am in First method"
break;
}

Function Second ()
{

write-host "I am in second method"

}


First
Second
```

Comment: Why are you using break in a function. Essentially the function is executing and breaking out of the script. Use return.

Comment: There are split views on using `Return` in powershell, but for your examples, you don't need any control mechanisms (break, return, etc.)

Comment: I agree. I just assumed this was a simplified example of a case where the OP has a function that needs to terminate early so I provided the way to do that.

Comment: thanks return worked, actually in my real code, i use foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest against using `*-Host` functions unless you need them for a particular reason, and use an approved verb-noun naming convention (`Get-Verb`).  `break` is a keyword intended to *break* out of loops (`foreach`, `for`, `while`, etc.)

Re-written:

```
Function Get-First
{
    'I am the First function.'
    # equivalent to: Write-Output 'I am the First function.'
}
Function Get-Second
{
    'I am the Second function.'
}
Get-First
Get-Second
```